# Moving a div slightly up or down depending on the viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations, parallax

I have a one-page design to implement and it looks like a few cut out pages of a magazine laid down vertically and overlapping each other slightly. They have some fray and holes at the top, respective bottom of each page, so you can see which page is on top and which is underneath in the small zone where they overlap.

I would like now to have each of this areas to move slightly up or down when scrolling, so it gives an illusion of dimension.

But I can't wrap my head around it how to do it. I searched for half a day, but the closest I could find was parallax effects. That's pretty close, but I want the whole div to move, not just a background image.

But the parallax effects make a background image move, while I need to have a full wrapping div to move slightly.

So basically just like 3 wrapping elements with a lot of content and styling and when the viewport gets from wrapper1 to wrapper2 I need wrapper1 to move a bit down and wrapper2 to move a bit up. If I scroll back up the opposite shall happen.

```
<div id="wrapper1">Lots of content and more divs</div>
<div id="wrapper2">Lots of content and more divs</div>
<div id="wrapper3">Lots of content and more divs</div>
```

Any ideas or tips would be very welcome. Or maybe another effect that would let me archive this illusion of movement for whole layers.

Answer (score 0):

One CSS only idea is using the `perspective` property on the container element and playing with the Z translation and scale to correct the dimension on your absolute positioned wrapper children elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper1 parallax">Lots of content and more divs</div>
  <div class="wrapper2 parallax">Lots of content and more divs</div>
  <div class="wrapper3 parallax">Lots of content and more divs</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  perspective: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.parallax {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper1 {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.wrapper2 {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
}

.wrapper3 {
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(2);
}
```

*and try [not to use id's](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/), use classes instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height: 1000px;">
   <div style="height: 100px; position: sticky; top: 0;">sticky</div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position